# How can I use the Waypoints script in other scripts for different waypoints and agents?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is attached to empty gameobject and in the inspector I assigned an agent.

but now I want to use the same script in another script for different actions.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> points = new List<Transform>();
    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    private int destPoint = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        var wayPoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint");
        foreach (GameObject waypoint in wayPoints)
        {
            points.Add(waypoint.transform);
        }

        //agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

        // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
        // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
        // approaches a destination point).
        agent.autoBraking = false;

        GotoNextPoint();
    }


    void GotoNextPoint()
    {
        // Returns if no points have been set up
        if (points.Count == 0)
            return;

        // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;

        // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
        // cycling to the start if necessary.
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Count;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Choose the next destination point when the agent gets
        // close to the current one.

        if (!agent.pathPending && agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
        {
            GotoNextPoint();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the other script I want to use the Waypoints script too :

but in this script I want the agents to move in other waypoints not the same waypoints the agent is moving between in the Waypoints script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class BodyScan : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<NavMeshAgent> agents;
    public GameObject transporter;
    [Range(20, 300)]
    public int timeVisit = 20;
    public string nextVisitTime;

    private int oldtimevisit;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var npc = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Npc").ToList();
        for(int i = 0; i < npc.Count; i++)
        {
            if (npc[i].GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>() != null)
            {
                agents.Add(npc[i].GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>());
            }
        }

        transporter = GameObject.Find("Pref_TransporterBlue");

        oldtimevisit = timeVisit;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(timeVisit != oldtimevisit)
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
            Debug.Log(Random.Range(20,timeVisit));

            var timetowait = Random.Range(20, timeVisit);
            StartCoroutine(Waiting(timetowait));
        }

        oldtimevisit = timeVisit;
    }

    IEnumerator Waiting(int waitingtime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitingtime);

        DoSomethingWithNpcs();
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithNpcs()
    {

    }
}
```

Inside the DoSomethingWithNpcs I want to use the Waypoints script to move the agents in different waypoints.

The goal is to be able to use the Waypoints script in many cases and different situations and waypoints and agents.

I tried this in the top of the BodyScan script I added :

```
public Waypoints waypoints;
```

Then in the bottom I did :

```
private void DoSomethingWithNpcs()
    {
        waypoints.points.Add(transporter.transform);
        waypoints.agent = agents[0];
    }
```

but now the agent in the Waypoints script that is attached to emptygameobject stopped moving stuck staying in a waypoint. and the agent/s in the BodyScan script moved between the waypoints with the new added waypoint the transporter and then also stuck stopped at the same waypoint the first agent is.

I want that one agent will move between the first waypoints and the second agent/s will move only in between he position and the new added waypoint and not between all the waypoints.

Comment: i dont understant what you want..its a great mixture....

Answer (score 0):

## Overview

I see you got pretty much stuff here, okay! Firstly what I'd do is to clean up slightly the code and I'd separate waypoint stuff from the AI, I see you got it mixed, my solution would be to keep waypoint script as a pure information for the BodyScan (and other AI's) where to go and Waypoints for the path, so I'll show you how I'd do it!

## The Waypoint class

So as I mentioned, I'd keep the waypoint script just as an information for the AI, **to do this we have to remove MonoBehaviour extension**, this allows us to maybe change it to list of Vector3's in the future, maybe add methods, and serializable flag makes the values easily accessible from the inspector, now we can even create it as we need it, so here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Waypoints
{
    public List<Transform> points = new List<Transform>();
}
```

Not a lot, but we just want to store information here, we may create methods to create new waypoints that also check if the waypoint is correct but it's just a suggestion.

## The Waypoint class usage

Here I'll slightly modify your BodyScan script but I may not get right the implementation, so feel free to make changes, the general idea is to use, something like you did, a reference to the class, and also instantiate it if we need it from script

```
public Waypoints waypoints;
```

And then to instantiate it in the code:

```
void Start()
{
    if(waypoints.points.Count == 0){
        waypoints = new Waypoints();
        waypoints.points.Add(transporter.transform);
    }
}
```

## The AI

Now that we have set our points, I suggest to make the AI track index of the point it was at, index of the target point and the waypoint list, I don't understand how you use BodyScan class so just read this implementation and try to understand it and implement it to your case:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Waypoints waypoints;
    public float distanceToContinue;

    private float currentDistanceToPoint;
    private int lastPointIndex;
    private int goalPointIndex;


    void Start()
    {
        //Firstly check if the waypoints are set up correctly
        if(waypoints.points.Count < 1){
            Debug.LogError("Set up the waypoints for this gameObject!");
        }else{
            //Now set up the path
            lastPointIndex = 0; //Start from the index 0
            this.transform.position = waypoints.points[0].position;
            goalPointIndex = 1; //Go to the [1] waypoint
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Calculate the distance and check if it should move to the next waypoint.
        currentDistanceToPoint = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, waypoints.points[goalPointIndex].position);
        if(currentDistanceToPoint <= distanceToContinue){
            //Save the old index, totally useless in this implementation though
            lastPointIndex = goalPointIndex;
            //Increase goal index to change the goal waypoint to the next, (Or maybe random one?)
            goalPointIndex++;
            if(goalPointIndex >= waypoints.points.Count)
                goalPointIndex = 0;
        }

        //Now move towards the current waypoint, Change this to fit your code with navMesh anyway I think I did a lot for you anyway
        transform.LookAt(waypoints.points[goalPointIndex].position);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. In the bodyscan script I make a new instance for the Waypoints class and update the points list. but then in the AI script there is a new waypoints variable that have no reference to the Waypoints class so the points list is empty.  where is the connection/reference between the SimpleAI script and the Waypoints class ?

Comment: The third snippet includes instancing of the waypoints through script, you can assign it like that or through inspector! It's similar to creating a box, where in the waypoints class we specify what the box is storing and in script we tell that we need 1 box, then in script we can say box = new box(); and assign box values after or in inspector we can tell it the values.

Comment: I understand that's why I added the code in the bodyscene script to the Awake and using a breakpoint it does make new instance for Waypoints andd the waypoint to the list but then when it's getting to the AI script the points list is empty. not sure why but the list in the AI is empty.